# how to share image to facebook via intent

Tags: android

I was wondering what is wrong in my code bellow ? why the image in Asset was not loaded to facebook share page?

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/images/end_level_10.png"));
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Congratulation! You get A+ with Kid IQ Game.");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Congratulation!"));
```

appreciate for your kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to share files (images including) from the assets folder through a custom `ContentProvider`

You need to `extend ContentProvider`, register it in your manifest and implement the openAssetFile method. You can then assess the assets via Uris.

add this to your manifest

```
<provider android:name="yourclass.that.extendsContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.yourdomain.whatever"/>
```

example class,

```
   @Override
    public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
        String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment();

        if(file_name == null) 
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
        try {
            afd = am.openFd(file_name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

return afd;
}
```

for refrence ,
[too-easy-using-contentprovider-to-send](http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2012/03/too-easy-using-contentprovider-to-send.html)

Comment: Note that the support library also includes [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) which is specifically built to allow easy sharing of files (including images from the asset folder) between apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
share.setType("image/jpeg");  
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/images/end_level_10.png"));
```

change the above code to

```
share.setType("image/png");
```

or

```
share.setType("image/*");
```