# Share image in Facebook programmatically from Android app via Intent

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent

I have this code working well on Android 4.0.4.

```
// Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// Set the MIME type
share.setType(type);

// Create the URI from the media
java.io.File media = new java.io.File(mediaPath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

// Add the URI and the caption to the Intent.
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);

// Broadcast the Intent.
mActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
```

But on Android 4.4.2 it crashes the Facebook app. Facebook app opens, the image is not shown and the FB app is dead.

In log dump I've noticed this message:

```
E/JHEAD   ( 5850): can't open '/data/data/cz.volten.brili.android.free/files/product_preview_shared.jpg'
V/ContextImpl( 5850): ----- packageName = com.facebook.katana is NOT LOCKED -----
```

Could the reason be some security restrictions, e.g. The FB app does not have rights to access the image in the application folder even though it is invoked from an intent?

If so, what would be a proper location for an image shared between the apps?

Shall I use something like this: [how to share image to facebook via intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603442/how-to-share-image-to-facebook-via-intent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could the reason be some security restrictions, e.g. The FB app does not have rights to access the image in the application folder even though it is invoked from an intent?

Correct. That image is on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) for your app, which is private to your app.

> If so, what would be a proper location for an image shared between the apps?

You can stick with internal storage, though you will need to use [a `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), perhaps with [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper), to serve the file. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrates this, albeit with a PDF rather than an image.

Or, put the file on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> Shall I use something like this: how to share image to facebook via intent

You could, though that would seem to be overkill, compared to using `FileProvider`.

Comment: Thank you. Looks great, I'll try it tomorrow (now it is really late in my timezone:)

Comment: Could you please briefly explain why is the legacycompatcursorwrapper used and what is its purpose? Can we also do it without it? The sample app is simple enough and I don't see any connection to legacycompatcursorwrapper other then "just" being there as a non-referenced java class...

Comment: @PerfectGamesOnline.com: "Could you please briefly explain why is the legacycompatcursorwrapper used and what is its purpose?" -- that is explained in the documentation that I linked to. It aims to help with compatibility with apps that do not use `content://` `Uri` values properly for things like `ACTION_SEND`. "Can we also do it without it?" -- more apps will crash when trying to respond to your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. "as a non-referenced java class" -- it is referenced in the `LegacyCompatFileProvider` class, used in the sample project.

Comment: Thanks. I see the connection between the FilesCPDemo and the LegacyCompatFileProvider is in the `AUTHORITY="com.commonsware.android.cp.v4file"` which is used in AndroidManifest.xml to define the provider.

Comment: @PerfectGamesOnline.com: Correct. `LegacyCompatFileProvider` is a `FileProvider` subclass, which in turn extends `ContentProvider`. The `<provider>` element in the manifest publishes the `ContentProvider`, for use by other apps. Note that my sample is for an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`; if you poke around, you should find some examples of using `ACTION_SEND` with `FileProvider` as well.

Comment: I followed your sample and the system gives me back user message "Please attach only photos". This could mean that the mime type is not correctly set. Would have a hint?

Comment: My code:
   java.io.File media = new java.io.File(mediaPath);
   Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND,
       android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, AUTHORITY, media));
 share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);
 mActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));

Comment: @PerfectGamesOnline.com: Well, `FileProvider` should be determining the MIME type based on the file extension. If you are using unusual file extensions, you may need to override `getType()` on your `FileProvider` subclass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86917/discussion-between-perfectgamesonline-com-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I usually use

```
    private void initShareIntent(String type) {
    boolean found = false;
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");

    // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) ||
                    info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type)) {
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Elevator Express");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath))); // Optional, just if you wanna share an image.
                share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        }
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
    }
}
```

and call it like this :

```
iniShareIntent("face");
```

Comment: Please explain how this addresses the issue from the question. The OP has an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` that is causing Facebook's app to crash. How does your solution solve that problem?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have this code and it has worked before for me on many devices. There is share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName); maybe that is the reason. It might help.

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely leverage from your code. I'll try it tomorrow (now it is really late in my timezone:)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.....here "updateImage" is my image location.

```
        if (isFacebookExist()) {


        if (hashClick.isChecked()) {


            SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(updateImage)
                    .build();


            if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
                SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                        .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
                        .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                                .setHashtag("#HashTag")
                                .build())
                        .build();
                shareDialog.show(content);
            }

        } else {

            SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(updateImage)
                    .build();


            if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
                SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                        .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
                        .build();
                shareDialog.show(content);
            }

        }


    } else {
        showToast(" Facebook is not install.");
    }


private boolean isFacebookExist() {

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```